# How to convert $\pi$ to base 16?

Tags: proof-explanation, approximation, pi, number-systems, transcendental-numbers

According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Approximate_value_and_digits) $\pi$ is approximately 3.243F in base 16 (i.e. hexadecimal).

Can someone explain this?  (Note: I understand how to convert an integer to base 16)

Thanks

Comment: How to convert to base 16: In base $16$ we have (by definition) $\pi = 3 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{16^n}$. From this it follows that $a_1 = \lfloor(\pi-3)16\rfloor$,  $a_2 = \lfloor(\pi -3 - a_1/16)16^2\rfloor$, and so on

Comment: This means $\pi$ is approximately $$3+\frac{2}{16}+\frac{4}{16^2}+\frac{3}{16^3}+\frac{15}{16^4}$$

Comment: Ohh.  Got it.  Thanks!

Comment: In case you are not only interested in converting any number to base 16, the [Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe_formula) (to compute Pi) might be worth a look, since it works on base 16 :-)
Oh - now I've seen that @azimut has told exactly this formula.

Comment: In practice you typically do it the other way round. You compute pi in binary/hex and then convert it to decimal.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way to convert any decimal fraction to base $16$ is as follows (taking $\pi$ as an example).$$\pi=\color{blue}3.141592...$$

> Take the whole number part and convert it to base $16$ as usual. In this case $\color{blue}3$ will remain as $3$. So we have so far got $3.14159..._{10}=\color{red}{3...._{16}}$
>
> This now leaves us with $0.141592...$ - Multiply this by our new base  to get $$\color{red}{16}\times0.14159...=\color{blue}2.26544...$$Now again convert the whole number part to our new base as usual - in this case the $\color{blue}2$ remains as a $2$. So we have so far got $3.14159..._{10}=\color{red}{3.2..._{16}}$
>
> This now leaves us with $0.26544...$ - Multiply this by our new base to get $$\color{red}{16}\times0.26544...=\color{blue}4.24704...$$Now again convert the whole number part to our new base as usual - in this case the $\color{blue}4$ remains as a $4$. So we have so far got $3.14159..._{10}=\color{red}{3.24..._{16}}$
>
> This now leaves us with $0.24704...$ - Multiply this by our new base to get $$\color{red}{16}\times0.24704...=\color{blue}3.95264...$$Now again convert the whole number part to our new base as usual - in this case the $\color{blue}3$ remains as a $3$. So we have so far got $3.14159..._{10}=\color{red}{3.243..._{16}}$

You can continue this process for as many digits as you require.

Answer (score 13):

Note that:
$$10000\pi=31415.92653\dots$$
which means that the decimal version of $\pi$ begins $3.1415\dots$.

Similarly:
$$16^4\pi=205887.46145\dots$$
Since $205887$ is $3243F$ in hexadecimal, the hexadecimal version begins $3.243F\dots$.

Answer (score 13):

For the particular base of $16$, there is this remarkable [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula):
$$\pi=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{4}{8n+1}-\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+6}\right)\frac{1}{16^n}$$
It allows the computation of any base 16 digit of $\pi$ without the need to compute all the preceding digits.

The discovery of this formula by Bailey, Borwein and Plouffe in 1995 came as a big surprise, as it was conjectured that no such formula can exist.

Comment: weird, for $n=0$ i don't get a $3$ that is the first digit in base $16$. Is this formula correct?

Comment: @Héctor According to [this source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) finding the nth digit is possible with this, but it is not as straighforward as plugging a certain n into this formula.

Comment: As @Jos already pointed the correct link, the name of this formula should be told: Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula.

Comment: @tueftl: ok, I've added the names and a link to the wikipedia page.

Comment: The really extraordinary of the formula BBP is the history fact that before it everybody though that the calcul of an irrational must be step by step, that was impossible to determine any digit of position n, say, whitouh determine the precedent digits. (sorry by my ugly english.

Comment: for $n=0$ it gives $47/15=\color{red}{3}.13...$ For $n=1$ it gives $102913/32760=3.\color{red}{1}41...$ For $n=2$ it gives $615863723/196035840=3.1\color{red}{4}15...$ So you can see how it is giving successive digits of $\pi$. You can try yourself [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%2F%288n%2B1%29-2%2F%288n%2B4%29-1%2F%288n%2B5%29-1%2F%288n%2B6%29%29%2F16%5En+sum+for+n%3D0+to+10)